# How can I send arguments(string) to the UI thread with the Background Worker?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, backgroundworker

I am using a Background worker on an application to update a progress bar on the UI. I am able to report the progress using the following.

```
backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(barProgress);
```

The problem is that the ReportProgress method only takes an integer as parameter, but I also need to pass a string to update a label on the progress bar.

```
progressLabel.Text = "Passed Argument";        
progressLabel.Refresh();
```

I can't seem to find a method to pass it directly on the BackgroundWorker object. Is there any method I'm not seeing or a way to do this?

Comment: `ReportProgress` has a second optional parameter that takes an object — that object is anything you want it to be.  From the ProgressChanged event, you would examine the UserState object from the ProgressChangedEventArgs parameter.

Comment: @LarsTech That would be a very good answer, and better than the one currently offered.

Comment: @LarsTech I had seen that overload, but I thought it was for something else. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The problem is that the ReportProgress method only takes an integer as parameter

Actually there is another `ReportProgress` method [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3zbdb1t(v=vs.110).aspx) that allows you to pass additional arbitrary object which then is accessible via [`ProgressChangedEventArgs.UserState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.progresschangedeventargs.userstate(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

For instance:

```
backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(barProgress, "Passed Argument");
```

and then inside the `ProgressChanged` event:

```
progressLabel.Text = e.UserState as string;        
progressLabel.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an [overload of `ReportProgress`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3zbdb1t(v=vs.110).aspx) that has a `userstate` parameter.  This of type `object`, so it can be anything you like.

So call it from your `DoWork` handler like so:

```
backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(barProgress, "Passed Argument");
```

And access it in your `ProgressChanged` handler like so:

```
progressLabel.Text = (string)e.UserState;        
progressLabel.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, you just need to call the `Dispatcher` associated with that control.

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(()=>{
    progressLabel.Text = "Passed Argument";        
    progressLabel.Refresh();
});
```

The UI runs in a **Single Thread Apartment (STA)** and usually doesn't allow *Cross Thread Access* (You might have gotten a *CrossThreadException* if you tried this before). By calling the `Dispatcher` you basically tell it what to execute when it's the UI-thread's turn to process again.

Just make sure you don't call `Dispatcher.Invoke` from the UI-Thread itself, that would deadlock it. If you have methods that can be called from either your UI or another thread, you can check if you currently have access with a hidden method (no autocomplete or IntelliSense) called `CheckAccess` that will return `true` if you can access that control directly or `false` if you have to use the Dispatcher.